# Difference between PagingDataAdapter and PagedListAdapter in Android Paging Libray Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

How do they work in the background?

I was a few familiar with the PagedListAdapter but not PagingDataAdapter(paging 3).
What is the main usage of PagingDataAdapter and differ with PagedListAdapter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PagingDataAdapter` is the Paging3 replacement for `PagedListAdapter`, it was rebuilt from the ground up to be Kotlin + Coroutines first, and supports synchronously reacting to LoadState + Errors (Paging2 didn't have these concepts built in), reactive transformations (including separators, LoadState-aware headers / footers via `ConcatAdapter`), and request de-duplication on top of a simplified API compared to Paging2.

To use `PagingDataAdapter`, it needs to hook up to the other Paging3 constructs via `Pager`, but all of these were built with backwards-compatibility with Paging2 in mind, so you can incrementally migrate from an existing project. e.g., `Pager` requires a `() -> PagingSource<Key, Value>`, but a `DataSource.Factory.asPagingSourceFactory()` exists for compatibility.

I highly recommend checking out:

- Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/index.html?index=..%2F..index
- DAC: http://d.android.com/paging3
- Android11 Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cwqGOku2a4

Answer (score 4):

If someone is migrating from Paging2 -> Paging3 and is searching like a madman for the `toPagingSourceFactory()` it's been renamed to `asPagingSourceFactory()` the docs don't reflect it yet.

Save yourself some digging and just use `asPagingSourceFactory()`

Comment: Thanks for this reminder, updated my answer. I've a hard time keeping track of things in SO!

Comment: How is this done in Java? I have not found any code doing so